# How to combine multiple jpg/image files into a single PDF using LibreOffice

Tags: windows, libreoffice

I'm used to working with Adobe Acrobat and really enjoyed the "Combine files in Acrobat" context menu in Windows 10.

I have recently installed `LibreOffice 6.3.5` but I haven't been able to find a straight-forward way of achieving this.

A few things I've tried:

### Writer

I can drag in multiple images, but they all get dumped onto a single page on top of one another. I see no easy way to make each file appear as separate pages.

---

### Draw

Same issue; I can import the image files but they just get plonked on the same page.

---

[This question from 2014](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/39089/open-multiple-images-and-save-them-as-one-odf-or-pdf-file/) using GIMP, which is fine, but I was hoping for a LibreOffice solution. Any ideas? The solution should be simple and GUI-based. I'm aware of the unix-based options but I'm after a GUI solution.

Answer (score 0):

LibreOffice Writer provides [full control of image attributes](https://help.libreoffice.org/4.4/Writer/Image), such as wrap and size. To prevent multiple images dropped simultaneously on a document from obscuring each other, turn **wrap off** and **prevent overlap** in the whole document, as shown below.

[image: Turn off wrap and overlap in Writer]

- In the *Styles and Formatting* pane, select *Graphics*, right-click, and *Modify*.
- On the *Wrap* tab, set wrap to *None*, and uncheck *Allow overlap*.
- Click *Apply*, then *OK* (A belt-and suspenders approach, but I find settings don't always work when first changed).
- Double check by opening the *Frame* dialog; the settings should have carried over.

Now, when multiple graphic files are dropped, the images should not cover each other. To separate them, press <kbd>Enter</kbd> after each for a line feed, or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> after each for a new page.

If you intend to do this frequently, change those settings in a template file, so you don't need to set them for each document.

In addition, the [free extension PicTool](https://extensions.libreoffice.org/extensions/change-multiple-images-in-writer-pictool) lets you set attributes of multiple images simultaneously. In the example below, all images were set to the same width, proportionally.

[image: PicTool]